# sed match word1 and word2 to get word in between

Tags: sed, awk, regular-expression

Im having issues with trying to pull an ip address our of a log file call full.

This is what the line in the file looks like

> [2016-11-10 11:22:42] NOTICE[24518] chan_sip.c: Registration from
>   '"100" ' failed for '62.210.189.39:6584' - Wrong password

I just need the ip address between `'` and `:`

Below is my attempt and getting this to pull out the ip

```
sed -e "/failed[[:space:]]for[[:space:]]'*.*.*.*:*'/,/[[:space:]]-[[:space:]]Wrong[[:space:]]Password/p" full > output.txt
```

Comment: `grep -oP '(\d{1,3}\.{1})+\d' FILENAME`

Comment: @Babyy that seems to drop off the last character `62.210.189.3` is the result I am getting.

Comment: You need an additional `{1,3}` at the end, then it ought to work.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic solution using `cut`

```
cut -d \' -f 4 < full | cut -d : -f 1 > output.txt
62.210.189.39
```

You may need to filter it down to just `Wrong Password` lines so here is something with that too.

```
grep 'Wrong Password' full | cut -d \' -f 4 |cut -d : -f 1 > output.txt
```

Here is a slightly more complex version using `sed`

```
sed -e "s/.*failed for '\([0-9\.]*\):.*/\1/" full > output.txt
```

Use grouping to pull out the IP address in parens

And just for fun I made one with `perl`

```
perl -n -e "/failed for '([\d.]+):/ && print \$1 . \"\n\"" full > output.txt
```

Also here is a `grep` command from the comments on the question that worked for me.

```
grep -oP '(\d{1,3}\.{1})+\d{1,3}' full > output.txt
```

Comment: The first cut -d worked really well. However it left some junk in the output file. Mainly dates and randomness

Comment: What about the sed and perl solutions?

Comment: sed left every line and just cut out the data about the ip address EX: [2016-11-10 11:15:31] VERBOSE[27827] config.c: Parsing '/etc/asterisk/manager_custom.conf': Found
62.210.189.39
[2016-11-10 11:15:31] WARNING[27827] media_index.c: Failed to stat /var/lib/asterisk/sounds/ru/incoming-call-1-accept-2-decline.sln: No such file or directory

Comment: Perl seems to be the ticket. However it is not adding a /n so I can read from the file later.

Comment: is there any way to implement a newline into the output.txt file?

Comment: Updated the perl answer to add newlines

Comment: You are awesome @Zachary. I appreciate your help. Now on to building my firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You say,

> I just need the ip address between ' and :

So let us use those characters as field delimiters and pick the IP address out:

```
$ awk -F "[':]" '{ print $7 }' file
62.210.189.39
```

If you wish to restrict the output to lines containing, for example, the string `Wrong password`:

```
$ awk -F "[':]" '/Wrong password/ { print $7 }' file
```

---

When dividing the line up on `'` and `:` as field delimiters, you end up with the following fields:

```
[2016-11-10 11:22:42] NOTICE[24518] chan_sip.c: Registration from '"100" ' failed for '62.210.189.39:6584' - Wrong password
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
field1         f2 field3                       field4              field5 field6       field7        f8   field9
```